# How can I solve items in my cart not displaying?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, material-ui, e-commerce

I have a cart that tracks items added into it and saves it to local storage under "ItemsinCart". However I am stuck on trying to loop through the items to display them on the check out page.

I have tried looping through the items in the cart. But have been unsuccessful in my attempts to retrieve the items selected. All my loop does is loop through the current card but does not show the current items selected.

Below is the original section where I have the store set up and can select an item. All items are stored in local storage. But I am unable to loop through local storage to show the selected items.

```
import React from "react";
import RemoveIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Remove';
import AddIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Add';
import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack';
import Badge from '@mui/material/Badge';
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import  stockmug from '../images/stockmug.jpg'
import ShoppingCartWidgit from './ShoppingCart'
import Swing from '../images/Swing-Stock-Photo.jpg'
import fork from '../images/fork-spoon.jpg'
import products  from "./product";
import ShoppingCartCheckoutIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ShoppingCartCheckout';
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Switch from '@mui/material/Switch';

import {
  Grid,
  Card,
  CardContent,Button,
  Typography,
  CardHeader,CardMedia,
} from "@material-ui/core/";
import tinkerbell from '../images/tinkerbell.jpg'
import mug2 from '../images/mug2.jpg'

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing(2)
  },
  cards: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(2)
  }
}));

export default function AltCard() {
    const [ItemsinCart, setItemsinCart] = useState(() => {
        // getting stored value
        const saved = localStorage.getItem("ItemsinCart");
        const initialValue = JSON.parse(saved);
        return initialValue || "";
      });
      


      const shouldDisabled = ItemsinCart < 1


useEffect(() => {
    // storing item count
    localStorage.setItem("ItemsinCart", JSON.stringify(ItemsinCart));
  }, [ItemsinCart])




    // getting stored value
    
  const classes = useStyles();
   

// ],   
// id for prouctremove
  

 
//  cart added here

 

  return (

    <>
      
        
        
        <div className={classes.root}>
          <Grid
              container
              spacing={2}
              direction="row"
              justify="flex-start"
              alignItems="flex-start"
          >
              {/* <Grid item xs={12}> */}
              {products.map((elem) => (
                  <Grid
                      item
                      xs={6}
                      className={classes.cards}
                      key={products.indexOf(elem)}
                  >
                      <Card>
                          <CardHeader
                              title={` ${elem.Title}`}
                              subheader={`price: $  ${elem.price}`} />
                          <CardMedia
                              component="img"
                              alt="a litter of puppies inside their doggie bed"
                              height="140"

                              image={` ${elem.imageId}`} />

                          <CardContent>
                              <Typography  
                              description={` ${elem.description}`}
 variant="h5" gutterBottom>
                                  A mug made by 
                                  <Stack direction="row" spacing={2}>
                                      <Button 
                                        value={ItemsinCart}
                                        onChange={(e) => setItemsinCart (e.target.value)}
                                      
                      
                                      onClick={() => {

                                    //  increase the amount of the counter by one and add to local storage
                                    setItemsinCart ( ItemsinCart + 1)
                                                                         
                                    ;}
                                 }

                                          size="large" variant="contained" endIcon={<AddIcon />}>
                                          Add To  Cart
                                      </Button>
                                      <Button
                                        disabled={shouldDisabled}

                                      id="RemoveFromCart" onClick={() => {
                                          setItemsinCart(ItemsinCart - 1);
                                      } } size="large" variant="contained" endIcon={<RemoveIcon />}>
                                          Remove From  Cart
                                      </Button>
                                      
                                  </Stack>
                              </Typography>
                          </CardContent>
                      </Card>
                  </Grid>
              ))}
              {/* </Grid> */}
          </Grid>
      </div>
      <Badge badgeContent={ ItemsinCart} 
        // invisible={invisible} 
      // aria-label={notificationsLabel(ItemsinCart)}
      
      color="primary">
              <ShoppingCartCheckoutIcon  size="large"color="action" />
          </Badge></>


  );
}
```

Here is the section where I am trying to loop through the items stored in the cart via local storage

```
import React, { useState,useEffect } from "react";
import ProductTile from './ProductTitle';
import products from "./product";
import CheckOutTest from "./CheckOutTest";


class Checkout extends React.Component {
    renderTile = (ItemsinCart) => {
        return <CheckOutTest product={products}></CheckOutTest>;
    }

    render() {
        let tiles = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
         

            const ItemsinCart = products[i];
            tiles.push(this.renderTile(ItemsinCart));
        }
        return tiles;
    }
}
export default Checkout
```

and here is the current check out page as I have it

````
import React from "react";
import RemoveIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Remove';
import AddIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Add';
import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack';
import Badge from '@mui/material/Badge';
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import  stockmug from '../images/stockmug.jpg'
import ShoppingCartWidgit from './ShoppingCart'
import Swing from '../images/Swing-Stock-Photo.jpg'
import fork from '../images/fork-spoon.jpg'
import products  from "./product";
import ShoppingCartCheckoutIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ShoppingCartCheckout';
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Switch from '@mui/material/Switch';
import CheckOut from './CheckOut'
import {
  Grid,
  Card,
  CardContent,Button,
  Typography,
  CardHeader,CardMedia,
} from "@material-ui/core/";
import tinkerbell from '../images/tinkerbell.jpg'
import mug2 from '../images/mug2.jpg'


export default function Check() {
    return (

        {products.map((elem) => ( 
      <Card sx={{ maxWidth: 345 }}
      key={products.indexOf(elem)}
      >
        <CardMedia
           title={` ${elem.Title}`}
           subheader={`price: $  ${elem.price}`} 
           image={` ${elem.imageId}`}
            description={` ${elem.description}`}
        />
        <CardContent>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="div">
            Lizard
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
            Lizards are a widespread group of squamate reptiles, with over 6,000
            species, ranging across all continents except Antarctica
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
        <CardActions>
         
        </CardActions>
      </Card>

        ))
    );
  }```
````

Comment: you say the code `loop through the items stored in the cart via local storage` yet ... there's no reference to local storage in that code block ... did you forget to actually read local storage?

Comment: you are not correctly retrieving and displaying the items from local storage

Comment: Are you event storing the right thing in your localstorage? Or is it just count?